# instrumenting arguments and return value of class's static and instance methods

Tags: javascript, class, instrumentation

I am trying to log the input arguments and return value of a method called.

```
class A {
    constructor () {
        this.x = 'x'
    }

    callinstance(x){
        // i want to log above value of x without changing class code
        if (typeof this.x !== 'string') throw new Error('this.x MUST_BE_STRING')
        return x + 1
        // i want to log value to be returned without changing code
    }
}

A.callstatic = function(x){
    // i want to log above value of x without changing class code
    return x + 2
    // i want to log value to be returned without changing code
}

A.a = 'a' // a static property should't be touched

// i can't change above code. i also cannot put a log in the actual methods

// now here is the soution, but runs into stack overflow. For obvious reasons.
const instrument = function(prop, static) {
  return function (...args) {
      if (!static) static = this      
      console.log(args) // here instrumenting inputs
      const t = static[prop](...args)
      console.log(t) // here instrumenting return values
      return t
  }
}

// overriding all the static methods
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A).filter(p => typeof A[p] === 'function').forEach((prop) => {
  A[prop] = instrument(prop, A)
})
// overriding all the instance methods
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A.prototype).filter(p => typeof A.prototype[p] === 'function' && p !== 'constructor').forEach((prop) => {
  A.prototype[prop] = instrument(prop)
})


// validation
console.log(A.callstatic(1))
console.log((new A()).callinstance(11))
console.log(A.a)
```

Solution above going in stack overflow for obvious reasons.
Any workaround to achieve my goal? without changing the class code?

PS : this is not a homework, i am just curious to have a solution for debugging tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is getting stack overflow error because you are overriding your own method
which means

```
/*
A[prop] = instrument(prop, A);  <-- this turns into as followed (replacing A[prop] to method name)

function callinstance = () {
      console.log(args) // here instrumenting inputs
      const t = callinstance(...args) // <-- recursion happens here
      console.log(t) /
}
```

You can do some work around to solve this problem, create a copy of the function, and override your class method, inside your custom function call the **oldMethod**

```
// overriding all the static methods
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A).filter(p => typeof A[p] === 'function').forEach((prop) => {
    let oldMethod = A[prop];
    A[prop] = function(args) {
                    console.log(args);
                    let x = oldMethod(args);
                    console.log(x);
                };
})

// overriding all the instance methods
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A.prototype).filter(p => typeof A.prototype[p] === 'function' && p !== 'constructor').forEach((prop) => {
    let oldMethod = A.prototype[prop];
    A.prototype[prop] = function(...args) {
                    console.log(...args);
                    let x = oldMethod.call(this, ...args);
                    console.log(x);
                };
})
```